# Updating status bar item legend causes memory complications

Tags: swift, macos, memory-management

I'm making an app for displaying CPU temperature on the status bar (continuously), and I'm running into a memory problem. Consider the following excerpts:

```
func statusBarInit() {
    statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)
    statusBarItem.button?.title = "0"
}

// Function called through an NSTimer:
func updateTemperature() {
    var temperature = String(getTemperature())
    statusBarItem.button?.title = "\(temperature)" // Problem
// statusBarItem.button?.title = "Fixed string" // Problem too.
}
```

I create the timer from `applicationDidFinishLaunching` as:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.updateTemperature), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

The problem is that the assignment to `statusBarItem.button?.title` causes increased memory use, rising by discrete steps of 300 KB every minute (stepwise, not continuously), which is evident from the Activity Monitor instrument and the Memory debug pane. However, the leak detection instrument doesn't detect any leaks.

I can tell that the fault is not caused by the getTemperature() function because if I set the `statusBarItem.button?.title` with a fixed string (and comment out the call to `getTemperature()`) the problem remains. With no string assignment at all to `statusBarItem.button.title` there's no problem.

Maybe the timer frequency (100) is too fast? Actually, the temperature sampling code works ok with the given period.

Other code looks like:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusBar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()
    var statusBarItem : NSStatusItem = NSStatusItem()
    ...
}
```

Comment: 100 times per second is pretty much too much. Consider that the human eye cannot even "count" 24 pictures per second... ;-)

Comment: Actually I'm using that high frequency in order to have the "leak" show up faster. At 100 Hz the leak shows in 2 minutes. At 10 Hz it's about 10 minutes.However, maybe the high frequency itself "induces" the leak, instead of diagnosing it.